# Use the CKEditor built-in whitelist engine to sanitize HTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Is there a way to use the CKEditor (4.4.x) built-in whitelist engine to sanitize HTML in JavaScript? I mean, let's say I already loaded CKEditor in my page and I have a string variable containing HTML, is there a way to invoke the CKEditor filters on the string to get a sanitized, whitelisted version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, looks like it may be `CKEDITOR.instances['myCKEInstance'].dataProcessor.toHtml(myHTMLstring)`.

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor

Comment: This seems to be the accepted answer, already tested it. If the admin thinks I should delete my question, please let me know.